# URL rewriting errors in my htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

everyone..

I need to rewrite this URL

```
http://www.mydomain.com/profiles/tutors/index.php?tutorCode=1255&tutorName=Kasun%20Perera&city=Bandarawela
```

like this

```
http://www.mydomain.com/profiles/tutors/1255/Kasun+Perera.html
```

I tried this with Apache’s mod_rewrite feature. But I couldn't reach to my expecting result.

Here is Code that I have tried.

```
RewriteEngine on
```

For specific teacher:

```
RewriteRule ^lanka_institute/profiles/tutors/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z\+\-]+)/([A-Za-z\+\-]+)/$ index.php?tutorCode=$1&tutorName=$2&city=$3
```

It is not working and then I can get this error message.

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

any comments are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Check the server log to see where you're going wrong.

Comment: +1 good question. Please go back and accept answers so more people will be willing to help.

Comment: what happened to `&city=Bandarawela` part of URL?

Comment: @Levon Please don't use blockquotes for code. And also don't add newlines to code.